# cakephp compare database fields in find

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-model

I'm using CakePHP 2.1

I have following fields in database.

```
id
views
max_views
```

I want to fetch records which has `views < max_views` using find query. So what should be the query for it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd do it like that.

```
$this -> find('all', array('conditions' => array('views < max_views')));
```